# Python how to patch entire object with patch.object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

Python's `unittest.mock` built-in library provides [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object), which let's you:

> patch the named member (attribute) on an object (target) with a mock object.

With regular `patch`, you can easily replace an entire object with a `MagicMock`.

**Is it possible to one patch an entire object (and not just one attribute) using `patch.object`?**

I am using Python 3.8.6.

---

**Research**

It seems this question was asked 4.5 years ago: [How to mock use patch.object to patch the whole object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234302/how-to-mock-use-patch-object-to-patch-the-whole-object-in-python)

However, no one answered, and the OP also seems to have had bugs elsewhere in his system.

---

**Motivation**

Why not just use `patch`?  Because it's just easier, when the object is already imported, to use `patch.object` on it directly, instead of having to think about what target to provide to a regular `patch`.

Comment: Why not use `patch` for that? It allows you to replace an object with your own (a `MagicMock` is just the default). Maybe I didn't understand the question...

Comment: Yes @MrBeanBremen I have added a motivation section to the answer.  It may not be the most quantitative motivation, but I just find myself often wishing I could use `patch.object` on an entire object.  Also, thank you for responding.

Comment: So basically you want to [monkeypatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class) an object. In `pytest` there is the `monkeypatch` fixture to do this, I don't know a similar feature in  `unittest`. You could always roll your own, of course, for example by writing a simple context manager that patches the object and restores it on exit.